# reflect property value on swift 2.0

Tags: swift2

how can I fetch the property value on swift 2.0?
on swift 1.0, I can get the Mirror value by value property, but I cannot find an API do this. New Mirror type on swift 2.0 only has few api. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the usage of reflection is swift 2.

```
let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: obj)
for child in mirror.children {
    guard let key = child.label else {
        continue
    }
    let value = child.value

    // use value or key here
}
```