# Equatable Testing in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, equality, nsobject, value-type

I'm looking for suggestions on good practices to test the equality of swift objects

If I have a complex object with many properties it's easy to miss the equality implementation.

What are the good practices to enforce the equality implementation?

**More details:**
Of course, you can write tests to check that two value are equal when they should, but the problem here is that this can break easily. 
You have a struct in your project, after six months another developer adds a property to that struct. 
Assume that he forgets to add the property to the equality. The equality still works, the tests pass but your app will break when only that property changes. My question is, there is a way to avoid this problem?

In a non trivial app is really easy to end up having model objects with 10 values, and use nested model objects. So how can I keep under control the equality of my model objects? How can I reduce the human error risk in the equality implementation?

**Possible solution:**
One solution I have in mind is to write a script that looks at compile time for classes and struct that conform to a certain protocol

```
Diffable : Equatable {}
```

For all the classes/structs that adopt `Diffable` I'll check for the existance of a test file, i.e.:

For the class `Foo` I'll look for a test class `Foo_Tests_Diffable`

than for all the properties inside `Foo` I'll check for the existance of a test function that conform to the following name pattern

`test<property name>Diffable`

i.e.:

```
class Foo : Diffable {
   var title: String
   var color: UIColor
   var tag: Tag
}
```

I'll check for the following tests inside `Foo_Tests_Diffable`

```
func testTitleDiffable {
// Test
}

func testColorDiffable {
// Test
}

func testTagDiffable {
// Test
}
```

If all the script finds all the expected tests than the compile step pass, otherwise it fails

But this solution it's time consuming and I don't know if I'll be able to implement it, so any suggestion is welcome

Comment: Well, that's why you're adding tests, right? ;) It's a good practice to declare it as `struct` if it should be considered equal when all the fields are the equal.

Comment: Of course, you can write tests to check that two value are equal when they should, but the problem here is that this can break easily.

You have a struct in your project, after six months another developer adds a property to that struct. Assume that he forgets to add the property to the equality. The equality still works, the tests pass but your app will break when only that property changes.

My question is, there is a way to avoid this problem?

Comment: Please expand your question title and body to take your comment into account. For some reason the comments were hidden to me and I wrote an answer of little use to you.

Comment: Done thanks for the reply anyway

Answer (score 0):

I would create **unit tests** specifically for this purpose.

```
class YourObjectEquatableTests: XCTestCase
{
    func testPropertyOne()
    {
        var object1 = /* ... */
        var object2 = /* ... */

        object1.propertyOne = nil
        object2.propertyOne = nil

        XCTAssertEqual(object1, object2)
        object1.propertyOne = "different value"
        XCTAssertNotEqual(object1, object2)

        /* etcetera */
    }

    func testPropertyTwo()
    {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

Note: if you write your test cases *before* implementing the Equatable details, you're actually doing TDD which is very cool!

Comment: Thanks, But as I wrote in the comment on my question. My problem is that I want to "catch future" changes to the class or struct. 
If you add a property in six months how we can catch the fact that the equality needs to be updated

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it a lot but Swift has Reflection capabilities.

https://appventure.me/2015/10/24/swift-reflection-api-what-you-can-do/

So in your case, you can mirror a class and then put some conditions in your test.

for example, you can set a fix number or attribute or methods for a class in your test.

```
let nbAttributes = 6
```

and then check it:

```
aMirror.children.count
```

I wrote a simple example in the playground and if I add a method variable, the children count increases. I don't know if it's possible to check the methods though.

```
class toto{
  var io = 9
  var tutu = "yo"
  func test(){

  }
}

let toto1 = toto()

let aMirror = Mirror(reflecting: toto1)
aMirror.children.count
```

another link:
[Reflection in swift 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32932447/reflection-in-swift-2)

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, expanding on @Mikael's answer, you should probably use Reflection.

An example would be:

```
String(reflecting: obj1) == String(reflecting: obj2)
```